# How to use Hyper-V Guest as the DHCP Server for all Guests

Tags: hyper-v, dhcp

I currently have my Hyper-V host setup using an External-Network adapter created under my virtual switches. This gives my guests access to my hosts NIC for internet access.

I have a guest VM running and is my Domain Controller. This is all functioning.

Now what I would like to do is to run DHCP server on my Domain Controller. After installing it, my other guests continue getting their IP information from the host, instead of the guest DHCP server. Is there a way to configure it so all my guests look to my domain controller instead of the external network?

I did try putting both my domain/dhcp server guest vm and another guest VM on their own internal switch, but they can't get IP addresses.

Comment: Remove DHCP from the Hyper-V host.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being simple to resolve.  The secure boot feature was enabled on the Hyper-V Guest.  This is found on the guest settings, Security.  I unchecked the Enable Secure Boot option.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be related to the question. Changing the secure boot options shouldn't have anything to do with DHCP.